# Anonymous template typename/class declarations

Tags: c++, templates

I'm curious as to why anonymous template typename/class declarations are allowed, such as the following:

```
template <typename, class, typename> struct TemplateTest1 { int a; float b ; } ;
TemplateTest1 <int, int, int> tt1 ;
```

Can anyone explain the practical value of these anonymous types? Do they affect the expression of the templated structure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By *anonymous*, I assume you meant *unnamed template parameter*.

It's allowed, because *sometimes* you may not need the template *argument*, and so making it *anonymous* makes it clear to programmer that the argument is not used anywhere in the class, although it's not that necessary.

It is similar to the way a function with an unnamed parameter is allowed:

```
void f(int) //allowed
{
}
```

Comment: It now occurs to me that permitting the expression of std::enable_if conditions is a particularly useful application of these unnamed template parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The programmer may choose to typedef a particular template-instantiation, which should be used only with that type. One type may have `<int,int,bool>`, another type maybe `<float, bool string>`, and the programmer doesn't want them to be convertible. Underlying structure is same, but they aren't convertible.

It is like:

```
struct ABC
{ int a,b;};
struct XYZ
{ int a,b;};
```

Both types are same, but `ABC` is not convertible to `XYZ` and vice versa. Many of Windows handles are declared via `DECLARE_HANDLE`, and are not convertible.