# Assigning a type into the typename keyword

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I was looking at the following template function and was wondering what happens behind the scenes when we assign the `enable_if` type to the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type>
                    // ^^ What happens here?
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "T is a pointer!" << std::endl;
}
```

Other then the obvious SFINAE, does the compiler actually do something with it? Perhaps it generates some kind of anonymous type?

Thanks

Comment: It's an [unnamed template parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718094/anonymous-template-typename-class-declarations) with a default argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're using a lenient compiler which doesn't complain about the missing `typename` keyword after `=`.

It is an unnamed template parameter which is otherwise ignored, along with a default template argument which will be used if no other template argument is specified.

It means that `foo<void *>()` resolves to `foo<void *, std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<void *>::value>::type>()`, which is `foo<void *, void>()`.

It means that `foo<int>()` would resolve to `foo<int, std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<int>::value>::type>()`, except it gets rejected because `std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<int>::value>` doesn't have any `type` member.

It means that `foo<int, int>()` works and prints "T is a pointer!", since the default argument is not used if a template argument is explicitly specified.

That last one means this is probably not a good idea.

Comment: So is there anyway I can accomplish the same thing (Disallow template instantiation for non-pointer types) without the default argument (So your `foo<int, int>()` example will also fail)?

Comment: @user The usual way is putting the `enable_if` in the return type rather than in a template default argument: `template <typename T> auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>> { ... }`. A caller cannot specify a different return type. (You may need to use `enable_if<...>::type` and `is_pointer<...>::value` as in your question if your implementation's library hasn't been updated to allow the new shorter forms.)

Comment: Meh, `foo<int, int>()` is firmly in the Machiavelli territory for me.

Comment: @T.C. Agreed if it's done intentionally, but what if it happens by accident? What if some older version of the library did expect the user to supply two template arguments for `f` and gave the third template parameter a default, and the user updates to a new version of the library? Or what if `f` and `g` are very comparable but `g` takes an additional template parameter, and the user updates a call to `g` to call `f` instead?

Answer (score 1):

No, we're not assigning the `enable_if` type to the `typename` keyword, the template parameter is just ommitted here, because it won't be used:

```
template <typename T, typename Anonymous_Template_Parameter = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type>
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And `=` makes `std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type>` as its default argument here.